# Codeigniter url in crontab

Tags: codeigniter, cron

How to set codeigniter url in crontab

I have tried with

```
 * * * * * php-cli /var/www/html/msp/index.php partner cron_test
```

But it did not work

My application url is

```
 localhost/msp/index.php/partner/cron_test
```

My php code

```
public function cron_test()
{
    if($this->input->is_cli_request())
    {            
        $fo= fopen("/var/www/cron_test".microtime().".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");;
        fwrite($fo,"Cron tab test");
        fclose($fo);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "You dont have access";
    }   
}
```

Project located under /var/www/html/

Comment: Hi @Sinto that solution is for cPanel, But i am not working cPanel

Comment: There is answer which helps you.

Comment: @Sinto tried but did not work

Comment: Are you using CI2 or CI3? When you run `which php` from the command line what is the output? Also, try running `php-cli /var/www/html/msp/index.php partner cron_test` from the command line - does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Set correct php installation path or directly use php in command to execute your cron, if you want to find out your installation path try using command.

```
which php
```

It will give you installation path like used in below crontab command

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/msp/index.php partner cron_test
```

If you want to debug your cron url, you can directly run /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/msp/index.php partner cron_test command from Ubuntu terminal. It will show you the direct output So you can debug wheather it's working or not then set in crontab accordingly.

Comment: Hi Piyush tanks for the help, when tried to run directly it gave error The <b><b>ipconfig.php</b> file is missing! Please make a copy of the <b>ipconfig.php.example</b> file and rename it to <b>ipconfig.php</b></b>